# HipHop-Php VM and auto_prepend

Tags: php, ubuntu, hiphop

Does anyone know if it is possible to include an auto_prepend file with HipHop hhvm (latest version)?

I don't see in the options or the documentation anything about this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do this. I've love to get a pull request from you though :)

Answer (score 0):

Support for `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` was added in HHVM 3.1.0 (Released 2014). These behave the same way as their Zend PHP counterparts.

If running an older HHVM version, there was (and still is) also the `request_init_document` setting is similar `auto_prepend_file` in that it executes before the main script for this request executes.

However, it has two important differences:

1. The RequestInitDocument will not run once before every single web request. Instead, HHVM runs `request_init_document` only once a longer-lived thread. The state of the virtual machine after `request_init_document` completed is captured in a snapshot and then restored at the start of multiple future requests, until it gets recycled and recreated.
   [HHVM 3.22.0 - Server Flow Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/HHVM-3.22.0/hphp/doc/server.documents#L54-L71)
2. It applies only to web requests, not CLI. https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1323